# Converting a iphone app to universal application in xcode 4 error

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I am trying to convert a iphone app to universal app, here is my code

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

        //  self.viewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target: self selector: @selector (pullnextview) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        [self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target: self selector: @selector (Ipadpullnextview) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
```

==================================================================================

```
-(void)pullnextview
{
    [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    NSArray *viewsArray;
    //create the first view controller

    SearchViewController *navController0 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];

    navController0.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
    [navController0 setTitle:@"Neuen Termin buchen"];

    //create the navigation controller and use NavRootController as its root
    UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController0];
    UINavigationController *nav;
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int uid = [standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"dmloginid"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];

    if(uid>0)
    {

        SearchViewController *navController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
        navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appointment.png"];
        [navController setTitle:@"Meine Termine"];
        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    }
    else
    {
        LoginViewController *navController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appointment.png"];
        [navController setTitle:@"Meine Termine"];
        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    }


    SettingsViewController *navController3 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    navController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"];
    [navController3 setTitle:@"Einstellungen"];

    //create the navigation controller and use NavRootController as its root
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController3];
    viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav0,nav,nav3, nil];
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    //then tell the tabbarcontroller to use our array of views
    [tabbarController setViewControllers:viewsArray];

    //then the last step is to add the our tabbarcontroller as subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;


}

-(void)Ipadpullnextview
{
    [self.viewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    NSArray *viewsArray;
    //create the first view controller

    SearchViewController *navController0 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IpadSearchViewController" bundle:nil];

    navController0.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
    [navController0 setTitle:@"Neuen Termin buchen"];

    //create the navigation controller and use NavRootController as its root
    UINavigationController *nav0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController0];
    UINavigationController *nav;
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int uid = [standardUserDefaults integerForKey:@"dmloginid"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];

    if(uid>0)
    {

        SearchViewController *navController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IpadSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
        navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appointment.png"];
        [navController setTitle:@"Meine Termine"];
        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    }
    else
    {
        LoginViewController *navController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IpadLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appointment.png"];
        [navController setTitle:@"Meine Termine"];
        nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];

    }


    SettingsViewController *navController3 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IpadSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    navController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting.png"];
    [navController3 setTitle:@"Einstellungen"];

    //create the navigation controller and use NavRootController as its root
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController3];
    viewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav0,nav,nav3, nil];
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    //then tell the tabbarcontroller to use our array of views
    [tabbarController setViewControllers:viewsArray];

    //then the last step is to add the our tabbarcontroller as subview of the window
    self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;


}
```

==================================================================================

I am calling the two different function containing the same code but the .xib is different . After that when i went to run the code this error is coming.

==================================================================================

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "IpadSearchViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Can anyone help me. I am new in this section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your IPad XIB and connnect the view outlet by right clicking the view and then connecting the referencing outlet of view to file owner..It shall work fine

Comment: there is some problem into it. it's not connecting . in blank view i have added a view. after that i am trying to do what u have told. but it's not connecting.

Comment: ok..seems that u have not specified the class the XIB has to inherit..First click on file's owner ,it should show 6 inspectors(Rigth side of XIB)..choose the third inspector i.e "Identity inspector" and chnage its class to "SearchViewController"..then try the previously mentioned steps..and ur good to go :)

Comment: in your case u can type in "ViewController" or any other controller u wish to display for the corresponding XIB

Comment: i did this, but app is quitting from Ipad simulator. And the err is,   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SearchViewController 0x7c78170> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Try adding another viewcontroller name in the identity inspector typically a class name Eg :"ViewController" or "LoginViewController" in your case